# Fail to load module Jupyter but not in Terminal

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, geopandas, rasterio

I am creating a conda env with the following commands in my Windows machine:

```
conda create -n s1 python=3.6
conda activate s1
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
```

Then, I install the `geopandas, rasterio, jupyterlab` packages:

```
conda install geopandas
conda install jupyterlab
conda install raserio
```

If I open python from terminal and load the packages:

```
(s1) C:\>python
Python 3.6.13 (default, Sep  7 2021, 06:39:02) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import geopandas
>>> import rasterio
```

Everything works. However, if I open `jupyter lab`:

```
(s1) C:\>jupyter lab
```

and try to load the same packages in a code cell, I get the following error:

```
import rasterio


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-350e27267e59> in <module>
----> 1 import rasterio

~\Anaconda3\envs\s1\lib\site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py in <module>
     20             pass
     21 
---> 22 from rasterio._base import gdal_version
     23 from rasterio.drivers import is_blacklisted
     24 from rasterio.dtypes import (

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

If I try with `geopandas`:

```
import geopandas
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-fc7d1d298f0c> in <module>
----> 1 import geopandas

~\Anaconda3\envs\s1\lib\site-packages\geopandas\__init__.py in <module>
      5 from geopandas.array import points_from_xy  # noqa
      6 
----> 7 from geopandas.io.file import _read_file as read_file  # noqa
      8 from geopandas.io.arrow import _read_parquet as read_parquet  # noqa
      9 from geopandas.io.arrow import _read_feather as read_feather  # noqa

~\Anaconda3\envs\s1\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py in <module>
     18 
     19 try:
---> 20     from fiona import Env as fiona_env
     21 except ImportError:
     22     try:

~\Anaconda3\envs\s1\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py in <module>
     83 
     84 import fiona._loading
---> 85 with fiona._loading.add_gdal_dll_directories():
     86     from fiona.collection import BytesCollection, Collection
     87     from fiona.drvsupport import supported_drivers

AttributeError: module 'fiona' has no attribute '_loading'
```

What can be the reason?

--- EDIT ---

From this question I see a solution would be to remove `rasterio` from my conda env and install it with `pip`. I would be okay with it but would prefer to stay with the conda instalation

[How to Fix: "ImportError: DLL load failed The specified procedure could not be found." when the DLLs are there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54083514/how-to-fix-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-f)

Comment: running `sys.executable` in Jupyter Lab gives me `'C:\\Users\\cstr\\Anaconda3\\envs\\s1\\python.exe'` So it is using the right one as it comes from the `s1` conda env. Btw, I am working on Windows

Comment: What do you get if you run this `jupyter kernelspec list` on the terminal. Available kernels will be listed. Make sure you use the correct kernel to run your notebook.

Comment: I get a list pointing to one kernel only, saved in the conda env I  just created

Comment: you are right in wanting to stay with  conda. Using pip after switching to conda negates the whole reason of using conda  for me  ie "no package conflicts"

Comment: maybe reinstall Jupyter instead

Comment: pip has proven to be more reliable than anaconda for me and the people I work with. I can help you set everything up with pip if you want to switch over from anaconda

Comment: can you include the output of `conda list` in your activated environment