# Can't import scipy in Spyder: ImportError results

Tags: python, import, scipy, spyder

I updated some packages this morning using `conda`, including `scipy`. The new version is 1.9.3. I can no longer import certain modules from my Spyder console:

```
>>> import scipy.special
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\igurin\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_19736\2717555404.py", line 1, in <module>
    import scipy.special

  File "C:\Users\igurin\Anaconda3\envs\latest\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 649, in <module>
    from . import _ufuncs

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ufuncs: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

It works in a "plain" IPython session (launched from the Anaconda prompt), though.

To make matters worse, I can't seem to use `conda` to install any version of `scipy` other than 1.9.3.

**Version info**

- Spyder version: 5.3.3  (conda)
- Python version: 3.10.8 64-bit
- Qt version: 5.15.2
- PyQt5 version: 5.15.7
- Operating System: Windows 10

**Attempted solutions**

- Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54083514/how-to-fix-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-f).
- Deleted my whole environment and reinstalled from scratch.

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54083514/how-to-fix-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-f)?

Comment: uhh... yes! That's what I started with. Then I wiped my whole environment and did a clean install. Didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer on [GitHub for Spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/19220). I removed Anaconda from my Windows path, and the import works now. I'm treating this as a workaround rather than a solution, though.