# Installing seaborn and scipy on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows-10, conda

I have a conda environment with Python 3.7 on Windows 10. Conda is version 4.5.11. It has pip version 20.0.2. I want to run seaborn and scipy libraries in Python. Following advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39945920/5289570), I downloaded .whl files from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) matching my Python version and 64-bit architecture. `pip install` on these libraries succeeded, and the libraries are listed in my environment. But when I try importing them:

```
import seaborn
import scipy
import pylab
```

I get a DLL load failure.

It's a mess getting some basic Python packages to work on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing numpy, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, and scipy. Re-installing via pip from the same link, then updating conda with

```
conda update -n base conda
```

EDIT: this [closely-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43549269/seaborn-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found) was also helpful. Perhaps a duplicate, but answers were not enough.